# Problems wrapping a const-member-function in a functor

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

We implement a system that passes callbacks to object-instance member-functions.  This works nicely, see the code below.  The problem is that the current state of the implementation handles only non-const member functions.

The code below compiles and demonstrates that the system is working.  As soon as the `/* const */` is included, it no longer compiles.

The error messages are localized not English, but the first message is 'incomplete type'.

Logically, a call to a const member-function should be not more constrained than a call to a non-const member-function, so it seems that the basic goal is sensible.
It is clear that the type of a const-member differs from that of a non-const member.  The problem is that we do not find a way to express to the compiler that the code is also valid for const members.

Where and how in the shown WrapP can we express that a const is acceptable?  Is it possible to define a single template that accepts both, const and non-const, member functions?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <auto F>
struct WrapP;

template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args, R(T::* F)(Args...)>
struct WrapP<F> {
    T* obj_;

    WrapP(T* instance) : obj_(instance) {}

    auto operator()(Args... args) const {
        return (obj_->*F)(args...);
    }
};

struct foo {
    // Const below is needed, but could not be activated.
    auto bar(double) /* const */ -> int { 
        return 314; };
};
int main() {
    foo x;
    // Create a functor for foo::bar
    WrapP<&foo::bar> fp{ &x };
    // Call the functor.
    std::cout << fp( 3.14159265  ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specialize `WrapP` for a `const` member function, you need to specify that:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args, R(T::* F)(Args...) const>
struct WrapP<F> {                                                   //  ^___^
 // ...
};
```

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a way to allow for *either* const or non-const member function pointers in a template parameter list, so you'll have to write separate specializations for those cases.

Comment: Completely obvious (*after* you showed me how to do it!).  That was it!  After adding that overload, everything works like a charm.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MichaelB No problem. Minor point: the correct terminology is "after adding a *specialization*", not an *overload*.

Answer (score 0):

Do not specialize `WrapP` -- instead keep taking `auto F` as your template parameter, and then extract the information you need using something like [Boost.CallableTraits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/index.html) or your own homegrown solution:

```
template <auto F>
struct WrapP {
    using T = boost::callable_traits::class_of_t<decltype(F)>; 
    using R = boost::callable_traits::return_type_t<decltype(F)>; 

    T* obj_;

    WrapP(T* instance) : obj_(instance) {}

    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args... args) const {
        return (obj_->*F)(args...);
    }
};
```

It is also possible to extract `Args...` but it's a bit more cumbersome as you get a `std::tuple` back.

Comment: Sorry, but boost is not an option for us.

Comment: @MichaelB: as I told you, you can use your homegrown alternative. The principle is the same, and CallableTraits is mostly just boilerplate to implement.